# TFS2017 - How to prevent team members seeing WIs outside of their area?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have a project that has been running for a while and has some external clients.  I'd like to configure TfS so that while the development team can see all the Work Items, the external clients / stakeholders can only see the work items which relate to their area and not any of the general development tasks or those relating to other stakeholders.

I tried to follow the [Microsoft guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/multiple-teams?view=vsts) for setting up multiple teams and areas (so will use their examples).

**Areas are configured as follows**

Fabrikam Fiber

-> Email

-> Web

**Teams are configured as follows**

Fabrikam Fiber (this team 'owns' the Fabrikam Fiber area and includes sub areas)

-> Email (this team 'owns' the Email area only)

-> Web (this team 'owns' the Web area only)

**Teams have the following members**

Fabrikam Fiber (whole development team)

-> Email (Adam only)

-> Web (Bill only)

**So logging in as the following I would expect to see:**

Development team. Can access whole project, both team projects and work items in any area

Adam. Can only access the Email team project and see work items in the Email area

Bill. Can only access the Web team project and see work items in the Web area

But what actually happens is that both Adam and Bill can see everything that the development team can (projects / work items).

**What have I done wrong and how can I make this work as I would expect?**  I'm sure I tried this in the past and it worked fine but that project now also has the same issue. We're using TFS2017 On Premises.

Thanks!

---

Update 30/04/2018

Thanks for the responses!

Step 1 of Cece's answer didn't apply to me as it's a single code base but Step 2 does mean that I can prevent the user from seeing work items in the other area - hurrah!

However I'm still stuck on how to prevent the user from seeing that the other areas exists at all (so in my example I wouldn't want Email to see Web listed on the homepage - as these are client names).  I had a better look at the Contributor group etc following Daniel's comment and having read the links Cece provided.  Logically I would expect that I should remove the Email team from the Contributor's group as that is Project level (and then they would only have their area permissions) but then all I get is a message saying 'This project only contains a default team.' There is also a tantalising Permission called 'View project-level information' but this doesn't seem to be editable.

I seem to have hit a brick wall again so any further advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's impossible to give a definitive answer. Look at the security groups assigned to the areas. Is one of them "Contributors"? Is everyone in the project a member of the "Contributors" group?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both [TFVC permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions?view=vsts#nbspnbspnbsptfvc-object-level) and [area path permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions?view=vsts#nbspnbspnbsparea-path-object-level):

1. Set permission for projects. Go the `version control` tab, select the project that you want to set permission, add the user, and grant **Deny** permission for `Read`.

[image]

2. Set permission for area path. Go to `Work` tab, select **Security** for the area path that you want to set permission, add the user, and grant **Deny** permission for `View work items in this node`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response - that's solved half my problem (preventing the visibility of work items) but the team itself is still visible and I can't work out how to stop that from appearing.  I've updated the question above.

Comment: Each team you create gets access to a suite of Agile tools and team assets. To control the users to access the projects, you have to set on each project. You may consider sending the team URL to the team members so they can start contributing to the team. For example: Email team: `http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam%20Fiber/Email/_dashboards`.

Comment: Are you saying there is no way to hide the teams a user is not in from their homepage or the project dropdown list?  I found this [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/5656801-provide-a-way-to-hide-teams-in-tfs-2013) so I suspect not.  This particular client has been using TfS for some time now on another of our projects and they are already familiar with navigating via the homepage and dropdown. In any case we can't risk exposing the names of our clients based on the hope they won't find the navigation.

Comment: For projects, you have to set for each project as I mentioned in item 1. For the homepage, do you mean `Team Member` widget? This widget shows the members for the default team only when you access `http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/TeamProject/_home`, not shows all members.